# ¿Cómo pasar un codigo de Python a PHP?

Tags: php, python, codeigniter

Necesito pasar un código que tengo en `Python` a `PHP` he tratado pero he tenido problemas.

**Código en Python**

```
from subprocess import *;
import json
import urllib
import csv
import sys

web_user = 'admin'
web_pass = 'admin'
lyric_ip = '192.168.1.202'
api_user = 'lyric_api'
api_pass = 'lyric_api'
api_version = '0.08'
url = "http://" + web_user + ":" + web_pass + "@" + lyric_ip + "/cgi-bin/exec"

class Mensaje:
    estado = -1
    contenido = ""
    destino = ""
    message_id = -1;
    def __init__(self, destino, contenido):
        self.estado = 0
        self.destino = destino
        self.contenido = contenido

    def queue(self, url, api_user, api_pass, api_version):
        args = urllib.urlencode({'cmd': 'api_queue_sms', 'username': api_user, 'password': api_pass, 'content': self.contenido, 'destination': self.destino, 'api_version': api_version})
        print args
        res = urllib.urlopen(url + '?' + args).read()
        obj = json.loads(res)

        if obj['success']:
            mensajes[i].estado = 0
            self.message_id = obj['message_id']
            print 'Mensaje insertado exitosamente. Ticket: ' + str(obj['message_id'])
            return 1
        else:
            mensajes[i].estado = -1
            print 'Error al insertar mensaje. Codigo de error: ' + obj['error_code']
            return -1

    def get_status(self, url, api_user, api_pass, api_version):
        if self.estado == -1 or self.estado >= 2:
            return self.estado

        args = urllib.urlencode({'cmd': 'api_get_status', 'message_id': self.message_id, 'username': api_user, 'password': api_pass, 'api_version': api_version})
        res = urllib.urlopen(url + '?' + args).read()
        obj = json.loads(res)

        if obj['success']:
            self.estado = obj['message_status']
            print 'Ticket: ' + str(self.message_id) + ' Estado: ' + str(self.estado)
            return obj['message_status']
        else:
            print 'Error al consultar estado. Codigo de error: ' + obj['error_code']
            return -1 


file = sys.argv[1]
csvfile = csv.reader(open(file), delimiter=';');
mensajes = range(0)
    i = 0
    for row in csvfile:
        mensajes.append(Mensaje(row[0], row[1]))
        mensajes[i].queue(url, api_user, api_pass, api_version)
        i = i + 1
```

**Código en PHP**

```
<?php 

$web_user = 'admin';
$web_pass = 'admin';
$lyric_ip = '192.168.1.202';   
$api_user = 'lyric_api'; 
$api_pass = 'lyric_api';
$api_version = '0.08';
$url = "http://" + $web_user + ":" + $web_pass + "@" + $lyric_ip + "/cgi-bin/exec";

class mensajedetexto {
    public $estado = -1;
    public $contenido = "";
    public $destino = "";
    public $message_id = -1;

    Public  function __construct($destino, $contenido){
        $this->estado=0;
        $this->contenido=$contenido;
        $this->destino=$destino;
    }

    Public function quenue1($url, $api_user, $api_pass, $api_version){
        $info = array(
            'cmd'=> 'api_queue_sms',
            'username'=> $api_user,
            'password'=> $api_pass,
            'content'=> $this->contenido,
            'destination'=> $this->destino,
            'api_version'=> $api_version);

        $args = urlencode(json_encode($info));
        echo $args;
        $res = file_get_contents($url + '?' + $args);
        $obj = json_decode($res);

        if ($obj['success']){
            $mensajes->$estado = 0;
            $this->message_id = $obj['message_id'];
            echo 'Mensaje insertado exitosamente. Ticket: ' + str($obj['message_id']);
            return 1;

        }else{
            $mensajes->$estado = -1;
            echo 'Error al insertar mensaje. Codigo de error: ' + $obj['error_code'];
            return -1;         
        }
    }
}

$gestor = fopen("archivo.csv", "r");
```

Comment: ¿Y donde tienes problemas? Creo que lo que intentas es pasar un algoritmo que ya tienes desarrollado en Python a PHP, por lo cúal te sugiero analisis el código y encuentres que es lo que hace y eso trates de replicarlo en PHP, no trates de tener visualmente algo parecido en ambos lenguajes.

Comment: Como siempre que hay una conversión de código, intenta elaborar un modelo en pseudocódigo del original, y a partir de ese modelo, desarrolla el nuevo código.  No intentes hacerlo directamente, pues la mayoría de las veces el código original nos condiciona y acaba por complicar el desarrollo.